# Selectively post form to different pages, based on form result?

Tags: php, html, post

Say I have a simple form on a page called `photo/delete.php`. This form deletes an image specified by the user. All it is, is this:

```
<form action="?" method="post">
 <input type="checkbox" name="confirmDelete" value="confirm" />    
 <input type="submit" value="delete" />
</form>
```

So, this form contains a confirmation check box that must be ticked to ensure the image is deleted. How can I dynamically choose what page to POST this form to, based on its contents?

For example, if the checkbox is not checked, yet the submit button is clicked, I'd like to stay on the same `photo/delete.php` page and display an error, since its possible they really do want to delete the image and simply forgot to tick the box.

But otherwise, if everything is successful and the checkbox is ticked, I'd like to POST it to another page, say `home.php` since it makes no sense to stay on the same page of a just-deleted image.

How can I implement this?

Comment: You wouldn't really change the form action. Instead, you'd either a) post to one and the same page, but make its output dynamic based on what happened; b) post to one and the same page, but, on success, include a header redirect (via PHP) that goes to home.php.

Comment: You need to implement some type of form validation, either server side (use PHP to check input fields and then choose appropriate action) or else client side (using JavaSCript or jQuery).  I would use a single value for the form action.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

**HTML:**

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="confirmDelete" value="confirm" />    
    <input id="btn_delete" type="submit" value="delete" />
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('btn_delete').onclick = function(e){
        var checkBox = document.getElementsByName('confirmDelete')[0];
        if(!checkBox.checked) {
            if(e && e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else if(window.event && window.event.returnValue) {
                window.eventReturnValue = false;
            }
            alert('Please check the checkbox!');
        }
    };
};
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/NMCqF/1/)